# Cross-project dependencies in Jenkins/Hudson

Tags: continuous-integration, dependencies, hudson, jenkins

I have project A and project B set up in Jenkins.  Project A stands proudly alone.  However, project B's tests rely on a live server instance of A.

The problem: when project A deploys, it takes the server down for some tens of seconds.  If project B is running tests at that time, they get borked, and baby Jesus cries.

I'm aware of the following solutions:

- Stub out A in B's tests.  (Too complex, not gonna happen.  And it's an integration test anyway.)
- Make B a dependency of A in Jenkins.  (Means we can't test B without kicking off A first.)
- Do a staggered deploy of A, so there's always one server live in the pool.  (We're looking at this, but it's not trivial.)

But is there a Jenkins solution?  I'd like to say "do not run task *deploy A* if task *test B* is running", but I can't figure out a way to do this without actually merging the builds.

Comment: It seems that A is a dependency of B: you have them reversed.

Comment: Yes, B depends on A, but as far as I can tell there's no way to express that relationship (or, more specifically, "don't build B while A is doing stuff") in Jenkins-land: you can only make A kick off B once finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two solutions I know of.

1. Use the [Locks and Latches Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Locks+and+Latches+plugin) and use the same lock on both jobs A and B.
2. Use the [Throttle Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Throttle+Concurrent+Builds+Plugin) with a category and use the same category on both A and B.

In both cases, neither A nor B will be allowed to run at the same time.

Comment: Locks and Latches appears to be deprecated now.

Comment: Throttle Plugin is the preferred one; offers more flexibility.